# tar cpf for the most recent file in directory with progress

Tags: bash, progress-bar, tar, gnu-findutils

I'm looking for the easiest way to tar the most recent file in directory. The command below locates the correct file, but I don't know how to tar it from the output:

```
find /home/user -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" "
```

And also I must output the progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a tar file with GNU tar append:

```
| xargs tar --checkpoint=1024 --checkpoint-action=ttyout='%u KB approximately written\r' -cf file.tar
```

**Update:**
GNU tar with progress bar (with `pv`):

```
find /home/user -type f -printf '%T@ %s %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | while read t s p; do tar -cf - "$p" | pv -s "$s" > file.tar; done
```

Output (example):

```
400MB 0:00:22 [74.2MB/s] [========================>          ] 77% ETA 0:00:15
```

Comment: Dear sir,
Your solution works for me. Thanks for that. However, i have 2 additional questions:
1- command execution prints the following message:tar: Removing leading `/' from member names. What is the meaning of the message? Does it remove the path of the file in some way?
2- Where i can learn more about the syntax of your command?

Comment: 1: [By default, GNU tar drops a leading `/' on input or output. There is an option that turns off this behavior.](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/absolute.html) 2: [More about Checkpoints](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_26.html#checkpoints)

Comment: Thanks, max appreciated!! And finally do you happen to have an idea of how to add progress bar to this process?

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe it:

```
find /home/user -type f -printf '%T@ %p\n' | sort -n | tail -1 | cut -f2- -d" " | tar -rf recent.tar
```

and then, create a compressed format

```
gzip recent.tar
```

or an older package extension

```
gzip -c recent.tar > recent.tgz
```

Please note that `-r` option in `tar` is used to append file in your package

Comment: Hello,Thanks a lot for your assistance. The pipe command seems to work, but it creates 10Kb file, which, of course, cannot be used. How do i create the tar for the entire file?

Comment: This will tar the entire file, this command: `tar -rf` has no instruction to split the file.